# How to open a file in non-blocking mode in devcpp?

Tags: c, file-io, nonblocking, dev-c++

I'm trying to write a server program in c, with DevCpp, that will create and edit about hundred of files every minute, of about 200 byte each.

The problem is that `unistd.h`, on devcpp, can't open files in nonblocking mode (it seems): I wanted to use `open()` with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag, but seems to not exist in the libraries (I have already checked in `fcntl.h`).

What do you recommend me to do? Should I search for another version of unistd.h, rather than the one provided by DevCpp, or should I use another library?

I wish to keep the code as simply as possible, in order to create a fast and reliable server program, in C language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: devcpp is dead and very old project. Try something else like QtCreator

Comment: I did some research. No, the problem isn't about the IDE. It seems it's just Windows that don't supports the `O_NONBLOCK` flag. I already tried the last version of [Pelles C](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/) and I found the `fcntl.h` to be nearly identical.

Answer (score 1):

The header for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and its flags is [`<fcntl.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html#tag_13_11).

Comment: the file fcntl.h exists, but it doesn't contain the O_NONBLOCK flag.

Comment: Then you are not on a POSIX-compliant machine, or you have not enabled the POSIX-compliance.  You might try O_NBLOCK (obsolete).  You might try `#define _XOPEN_VERSION 700` before any headers (or `-D_XOPEN_VERSION=700` on the command line).

Comment: I just tried, and obtained nothing. DevCpp is only for Windows.

Comment: OK - then you're on a hiding to nothing; use Windows-specific APIs.  The `open()` function is not standard C; it is standard POSIX. It may be available as `_open()` on Windows; it is not clear that all options supported by POSIX will be available on Windows.

Comment: I want to create an multi-platform programm. By the way, `_open()` don't seems to provide nonblocking support: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx). I start to think that the problem is that DevCpp is a very old project, as Michał Walenciak said in the comment above. I'll try to use another IDE.